# React state: unable to get updated value inside onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using an array of components that are interested depending on various conditions i.e the order and number of elements in the array are dynamic as shown below:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const comp = [];

    // if(condition1===true){
    comp.push(<MyComp onChange={onValueChange} />);
    // }
    // if(condition2===true){
    comp.push(<YourComp onChange={onValueChange} />);
    // }
    // if(condition3===true){
    comp.push(<HisComp onChange={onValueChange} />);
    // }
    setComponents(comp);
  }, []);
```

To each of the components in the array, there could be some sort of input control like input-text, input-number, text-area, chips, radio, checkbox, etc.
So there is an onChange event linked to each of these components.

I am using a common `onValueChange` function which is passed as a callback to these components. In the onValueChange I need 2 things:

- changed value (from child component)
- activeIndex (from same component)

```js
  const onValueChange = (val) => {
    console.log("onChange Valled", val, "activeIndex==", activeIndex);
  };
```

But here I am not able to fetch the updated value on activeIndex, it always gives zero no matter in what active step I am in.

<kbd>**`Sandbox DEMO`**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try using useCallback with dependency array. Also try to avoid storing components in state - the office advice - [what shouldn’t go in state?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state)

```
const onValueChange = useCallback((val) => {
    console.log("onChange Valled", val, "activeIndex==", activeIndex);
  },[activeIndex];
```

For rendering try something like below.

```
condition1===true && <MyComp onChange={onValueChange} />
```

or create a function which returns the component eg: `getComponent(condition)` and use this in render/return.  Make sure you wrap `getComponent` in `useCallback` with empty dependency array `[]`

Comment: You can update state inside setState

Comment: @Emmalex6250 - Yes, thats what `setState` do.

Comment: yes exactly have you taken time to try my solution.

Comment: I already tried useCallback, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {

    setComponents((previousValues)=>{
        // if you want to add on previous state
        const comp = [...previousValues];

        // if you want to overwrite previous state
        const comp = [];

        if(condition1===true){
          comp.push();
        }
        if(condition2===true){
         comp.push();
        }
        if(condition3===true){
          comp.push();
        }
      return comp;
    });
  }, []);
```